# Check if status changed in comparison to yesterday if yes display it in a new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Every day I run my code and its test if it was successful or fail.
I put it in a database and the database looks like this:

```py
         Date      Name Color
0  2019-07-18  Project1  blue
1  2019-07-18  Project2  blue
2  2019-07-18  Project3   red
3  2019-07-19  Project1  blue
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
5  2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

Now I want to display the only rows where it failed in comparison to yesterday

What I have now when I run my code is this output:

```py
         Date      Name Color
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
5  2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

I've tried to find the duplicate and save it in a new Dataframe

```py
dfnewfails = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last').query("Color == 'red'")
```

This is the output I want:

```py
print(dfnewfails)
>>> 0    2019-07-19    Project2    red
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['Status'].eq('FAIL')].drop_duplicates(subset='Name',keep='last')
```

Or by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query("Status == 'FAIL'").drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last')
```

Thank you @piRSquared  for suggestion -

> If there was a prior failure for a project but a subsequent success, Querying first would return the failure rather than nothing.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last').query("Status == 'FAIL'")
```

EDIT:

If need another condition for test last value of `Date`:

```
last = df['Date'].iloc[-1]
df1 = df.query("Color == 'red' & Date == @last")
print (df1)
         Date      Name Color
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
5  2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

Or:

```
last = df['Date'].iloc[-1]
df1 = df[df['Color'].eq('red') & df['Date'].eq(df['Date'].iloc[-1])]
print (df1)
         Date      Name Color
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
5  2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

If need condition for test today datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
today = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('d')

df1 = df.query("Color == 'red' & Date == @today")
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['Color'].eq('red') & df['Date'].eq(today)]
print (df)
        Date      Name Color
4 2019-07-19  Project2   red
5 2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

Comment: I would switch the order `df.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last').query('Status == "FAIL"')` because **if** there was a prior failure for a project but a subsequent success, Querying first would return the failure rather than nothing.

Comment: @Dijnsen - Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57096169/edit) question for better format data like in comments?

Comment: @jezrael  First of all thanks for your effort and time, I've updated my question.

Comment: @Dijnsen - So there are not values `FAIL` in column `Status`?

Comment: @jezrael There was but I recently changed it to colour, but I don't know why it prints Project3 when it already failed yesterday. I only want the ones who failed today and were good yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name',keep='last').loc[df['Status'] == 'Fail']
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a new way of doing it.

```py
print(df)
>>>         
       Date      Name   Color
0  2019-07-18  Project1  blue
1  2019-07-18  Project2  blue
2  2019-07-18  Project3   red
3  2019-07-19  Project1  blue
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
5  2019-07-19  Project3   red
```

First make the dates:

```py
today = datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
Date = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
yesterdayDate = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then the query:

```py
dfred = df.query("Color == 'red'")
dftoday = dfred.query("Date == @Date")
dfyesterday = dfred.query("Date == @yesterdayDate")
dfcombined = pd.concat([dfyesterday,dftoday])
dfnewfails = dfcombined.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep=False).query("Date == @Date")
```

Result

```py
print(dfnewfails)
>>>
         Date      Name Color
4  2019-07-19  Project2   red
```